# Please explain the ouput

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int b[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int n = &b[3] - &a[2];
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

The output of this question is -3, can anyone explain how is this coming?

Comment: I think this is what you want to be doing?                                int n = b[3] - a[2];

Comment: I believe this is actually somewhat interesting. Maybe if you could add more details to the question an choose **a proper title**, it would be OK.

Comment: You are subtracting addresses, not the values

Answer (score 8):

Subtracting "unrelated" pointers, i.e. pointers pointing in different objects is undefined.

C11-6.5.6-9

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;

Comment: From a practical point of view, `b` is most likely laid out so that its end is right where `a` begins. You can't count on it, of course.

Comment: @chris It's also just as likely for `a` to end right where `b` begins.

Answer (score 4):

`&b[3]` is a pointer to the 4th element in `b`, and `&a[2]` is a pointer to the 3rd element in `a`. `n` would then be the space in memory between the memory pointed to by each respective pointer.

I don't know if you can count on the resulting value (`-3`) being the same for all compilers. The two arrays `a` and `b` aren't guaranteed to have any relation to each other in memory.

If you were looking to take the difference between the VALUES of `b[3]` and `a[2]`, the code would be:

```
int n = b[3] - a[2];
```

which should give a result of `1`.

Comment: You cannot rely on it because it is [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25084328).

Answer (score 2):

The output of the code is machine dependent. You are subtracting the addresses of the elements. It may be different each time you execute the program

Comment: It is not machine but implementation dependent. Try it with an old and a new compiler (best for different addressing modes), and you might get wildly different results on the same machine. Anyway, it's UB so you might get a different result with the same implementation on the second run.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal because you're using the adresses

if you need the result to be 1 than use values like this

```
int n = b[3] - a[2];
```